# color changing happens all at once in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, codeblocks

i am making a program that is supposed to show you the stations to the sofia metro and i tried making it colorized, but then it turns out that it just shows the color of the last thing printed. i tried it on cxxdroid and it worked fine but on codeblox and several online compilers the issue seems to persist. what i

imagined happening is like the image attatched here:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/u03Fj.png)
vs what actually ended up happening:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1EqZ.png)

so my (simplified ofc) code looks like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<"chose on of the following lines to show their stations: "<<endl<<flush;
    system("color 40");
    cout<<"line one: Liulin  - Mladost (Business Park - Slivnitsa)"<<endl<<flush;
    system("color 90");
    cout<<"line 2: Nadejda - Lozenets (Obelia - Vitosha)"<<endl<<flush;
    system("color A0");
    cout<<"line 3: Ovcha Kupel - Hadji Dimitar (Gorna Bania - Hadji Dimitar)"<<endl<<flush;
    system("color 60");
    cout<<"line 4: Obelia - Sofia Airport"<<endl<<flush;
    system("color 00");
    cout<<"enter 5 for all 5 lines to be shown at once"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `system("color 40")` isn't standard, and I'm surprised that many compilers are coloring anything at all

Comment: The first item for color indicates the background, the second the text. Just swap all the values (e.g. A0 becomes 0A) and it should work.

Comment: I'm guessing you are trying to run on Windows? In Windows, the `color` command changes the color of the entire console. @MooingDuck The `system()` function is standard, and compilers must accept it. What is not standard is what the `color 40` command does. It could very well just be failing silently on other platforms.

Comment: Standard IO streams are targeted to support systems that have well below the sort of terminal you see on a PC. They are too "stupid" to understand things like colours. You'll need to use something smarter like the target terminal's API calls  or a terminal library like the curses family.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal , my point is that all 6 lines are shown with yellow (second image) while they are all supposed to be white red blue etc (image one) nevermind the background/foreground thingy.

Comment: So do you want each line to have a separate background color?

Comment: @jorkopeisct: The `color` sets the color of the entire terminal. It's working perfectly. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/color-cmd-command/

Comment: I think on Windows you can use a function called SetConsoleTextAttribute.

Comment: Just use ANSI escape signals in your printf lines: Black: 0x1b[30m Red: 0x1b[31m Green: 0x1b[32m Yellow: 0x1b[33m Blue: 0x1b[34m Magenta: 0x1b[35m Cyan: 0x1b[36m White: 0x1b[37m Reset: 0x1b[0m